# Images and animations used in my project are not getting displayed while running the JAR file of my project

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have made a project in JAVA using Eclipse. I have to send this project to someone such as he just double clicks and my project starts executing. For this I have created a Runnable JAR file of it but the problem is that the images are not getting displayed when I execute the JAR file. Sometimes, JAR file doesn't execute. 
Please help regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

What exceptions are we dealing with? Without that information it's pretty hard to know what you're dealing with and to get an answer. Have you already run the app on cmd with the command **'java -jar App name.jar'** ?

Comment: No exceptions are being shown up. I just see a blank white screen in front of me whenever I run the the .jar of my project. That's it.

Comment: did you run the jar using the command **'java -jar Appname.jar'** ? It is important that you run this command on cmd because if there are any issues that you may not yet know, they will show up there, that is, if the app runs on eclipse and not as a runnable jar file.

Comment: Hey, yes, it is running now atleast. But I am seeing a problem here. When I run the .jar file the images that I have used in my project are not getting displayed. Not even a single image. Though they are getting displayed perfectly when I run the project in Eclipse. Can you please help with that ?

Comment: It is very hard to help you if you don't answer our questions. I've asked you several times if you ran the jar file using cmd with the command **java -jar AppName.jar** where AppName is the name of your application. If your application runs on eclipse but not as jar file you need to run this command in order to know what may be going wrong. I have an idea that you may not be getting the files using an URL which you need if the images are also exported into the jar file. But without knowing the exception(cause) it could be many things which we don't have an answer for.

Comment: Yes, I ran the jar file using cmd with the command java -jar Nameofmyapp.jar . There are no exceptions being shown there. The jar file is running but images are not getting displayed.

Comment: What code do you have when you throw the exception for the images in case they were not found?

Comment: I have not used any such code. One thing I would like to tell you that I am getting 'duplicate entry' warnings for all my images while creating the runnable jar file.

Comment: When you are using files/Images you need to have confirmation that the file is where it should be. If the file is not created or isn't in a place the program can locate, it must throw an exception so that we can see what went wrong, otherwise only when errors occur will you see something is wrong. Since the images are already in the jar file, when you run the code to read the image, you must have a try catch clause or have the exception being thrown in case the file was not found by the program. First do that, then check if the app is able to find the files using the command I've mentioned.

Comment: Are you saying that for images wherever I have used Imageicon as JLabel in my program, I should put that code in try catch clause ?

Comment: I tried applying the try catch clause for one image only at first. I ran the program using java -jar AppName.jar . The images didn't load (as expected). But I am not seeing any exceptions or errors or anything. Please help.

Comment: ArcNub Gamer , the issue is resolved. Thanks a lot for your help. :)

Comment: Good to hear. Glad i was able to help you.